# Running x64 failed on VisualStudio2017 on AWS Workspace

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services

My environments are below.

AWS workspace - windows 10
Visual studio 2017 community edition

I tried to run sample x64 console code on my AWS workspace.  But it failed every time.  Even if I tried it with VS2015, the result was same.

If switching to x86, it works.

[image]

[image]

Is it possible to use VS2017 for developing x86 on AWS workspace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AWS workspace is a kind of VM.  So visualstudio debugger is not able to work under the host environment.  The only workaround is remote debugging outside the host.